# react-native-pages how to find out current index from parent pages component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to use [react-native-pages](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-pages) in a project, what i need is to use the onScrollEnd callback function to figure it on which page the user have scrolled and do some state changes based on the index, i know that the children components get an index prop but that didn't benefit me much. how can i know the current index from the parent pages component? what i have now in my code is a very basic implementation

```
function pagesContainer(){

return(<Pages startPage={currentPageNumber == 1}
        onScrollEnd={() => { console.log("i want to find out index and use it here") }} >
        <Texts pageNumber={currentPageNumber} />
        <Texts pageNumber={variablePageNumber} />
        <Texts pageNumber={variablePageNumber} />
    </Pages>);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options:

1. Use a state management solution (the built-in [React Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) should be fine for this, but there are many to choose from if you search them out).  Then you can set the active page number from anywhere (i.e., your Texts component, which gets the index prop) and consume it in the parent.
2. Use a library that's maintained (for example [this one](https://github.com/dohooo/react-native-reanimated-carousel), although I haven't used it personally).  The one I linked gives you an index as part of its `renderItem` callback prop.

Comment: well i don't wanna use redux or context api just for something trivial like that. i tried using that library but it's missing the extremely critical aspect of RTL support (despite mentioning it in their docs)..i guess i'm going to search through paging components and hope i find something